# Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;
    watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                                   expirationHandler:^{
                                                                       watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                                   }];


    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"NearestFacility"]) {

        [self NearestFacilityClicked];
        if (self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility.count>0) {
            NSDictionary *response = @{@"response" : self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility};
            reply(response);
  ;      }
    }    

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1),    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
    });    
}
```

when trying to send `NSMutableArray` to Watch from iPhone app extension then it gives below error.

> Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "

The `UIApplicationDelegate` in the iPhone App never called `reply()`  nsmutablearray

can anyone help me , how can I send `NSMutableArray` to watch from iPhone app, and this is dynamic array coming from REST request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835694/the-uiapplicationdelegate-in-the-iphone-app-never-called-reply) To Achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSKeyedArchiver`.

**on iPhone:**

```
NSData *objectData =
    [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility];
NSDictionary *response =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objectData forKey:@"response"];
reply(response);
```

**on Watch:**

```
NSData *objectData = replyInfo[@"response"];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objectData];
```

See also http://www.kristinathai.com/watchkit-best-practices-for-sharing-data-between-your-watch-and-ios-app/

**EDIT**

The thing is the reply() handler should be called in any case but in your example if `[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] is NOT NearestFacility` OR `self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility.count == 0`  the handler never won't be called.

Try the following code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;
    watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                                   expirationHandler:^{
                                                                       watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                                   }];


    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSDictionary *response = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"NearestFacility"]) {

        [self NearestFacilityClicked];
        if (self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility.count>0) {
            NSDictionary *response = @{@"response" : self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility};
        }
    }

    reply(response);

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1),    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
    });    
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    // set a background task
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
    backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        reply(nil);
    }];

    // do something
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"NearestFacility"]) {

        [self NearestFacilityClicked];
        if (self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility.count>0) {
            NSDictionary *response = @{@"response" : self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility};
            reply(response);
        }
    }
    reply(nil);

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 2), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // end background task
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    } );
}
```

Comment: Dear Kosuke,  still i am getting same error after using NsKeyedArchiver  and the error is : WatchKit Extension[569:71845] Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}

Comment: Dear Kosuke, still it's not working in suspended state of application, i am running watch application and my iPhone app is in suspended state, if i put application in Active or in background state then its working fine for me, its sending the data from iPhone app to  Watch app, but not working in suspended state :(

Comment: `dispatch_semaphore_t` could not be required.  I edited my answer. ref. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/73684#73684

Comment: Dear Kosuke, still i am getting same error     :(  DHADoctors WatchKit Extension[1112:320617] Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}

Comment: iOS 9.0.2 and watch OS 1.0.1

Comment: @DevD Sorry I can't help you... You don't need to accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks Kosuke for your help and prompt reply , thank you so much :)